# How to Multi Count, Group, Join and Where Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

This my table

[image]

I want Create this Result

[image]

Can i create that, in My Model ?
This is My Model :

```
function test(){
$this->db->select('a.id, a.name, a.city, COUNT(*) AS totala');
$this->db->select('b.name, COUNT(*) AS totalb');
$this->db->from('tabela as a');
$this->db->join('a.name = b.name');
$this->db->group_by('a.name');
$this->db->order_by('a.id','DESC');
$this->db->where('city'='BDG');
return;
```

Please Your Help

Answer (score 1):

**Your Schema**

[image: Table A]
[image: Table B]

**Query**

```
SELECT table_a.name, table_a.a_total, table_b.b_total
FROM (
    SELECT a.name as name, count(a.name) as a_total 
    FROM test.table_a as a
    group by a.name
) as table_a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT b.name as name, count(b.name) as b_total 
    FROM test.table_b as b
    group by b.name
) as table_b
ON table_a.name = table_b.name
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your answer but how Convert that to my model?

Comment: sorry @R.Drum I'm not Code-igniter expert, but I would suggest if you follow code-igniter query builder syntax for nested queries you can achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is a MySQL query that does the trick:

```sql
SELECT tablea.name as "NAME", totala as "TOTAL A", totalb as "TOTAL B"
FROM (
    SELECT `name`, count(*) AS totala
    FROM A
    WHERE city = 'BDG'
    GROUP BY `NAME`
) AS tablea
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT `name`, count(*) AS totalb
    FROM B
    WHERE city = 'BDG'
    GROUP BY `NAME`
) AS tableb 
ON tablea.name = tableb.name;
```

I don't know if it's possible with your querybuilder. Maybe add it as raw query or glue the result of two queries together.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer but how about in my model?. How to convert in my model?

Comment: When the model has an attribute name, total a and total b, you can convert it to a model. But I should handle this as a scalar value, not with a model.

Answer (score 0):

Its not the cleanest but this should work:

```
$where = "city = 'BDG'";
$group = "NAME";
$where = "ID ASC";

function test($where,$group,$order){
    $this->db->select("a.name, a.city, COUNT(*) AS totala, (select count(b.id) from tableb as b where a.name = b.name) as totalb");
    $this->db->from('tabela as a');
    $this->db->group_by($group);
    $this->db->order_by($order);
    $this->db->where($where);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i getting error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near"

Comment: I have updated the syntax and tidy it
error happen because count(b.*)